# How to log the POST request data before the validation?

Tags: php, restler

Is there a way to log the received POST request data before the data validation stage implemented via Restler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onValidate event, it fires just before validation starts

```
//in your index.php after $r = new Restler()

$r->onValidate(function() use ($r){
    Logger::log($r->getRequestData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy them to a variable, and validate values inside the variable:'

```
$my_post = $_POST;

//consider we want to validate some query-parameter called q

if(isset($my_post['q']) && ! empty($my_post['p'])) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This actually will not work since the Restler Validator will throw exception before your function is called.